# kubectl exec does not work with kubectl proxy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I wanted to execute `kubectl exec` command and connect to a container, so that I can execute some commands on it.
I have set the proxy with the following command:

```
kubectl proxy -p=8080 --kubeconfig=/directory_path/remote-kubeconfig &
```

proxy started running. I tried executing `kubectl exec` command:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod> --namespace=<namespace> -c <container> -- ls -l
```

I got the following error:

```
error: unable to upgrade connection: <h3>Unauthorized</h3>
```

Did I missed anything while executing `kubectl exec` command ?? Please help.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to the kubernetes cluster? E.g. can you call "kubectl get nodes" ?

Comment: Yes, I can run the "kubectl get nodes".  Problem is with running "kubectl exec" commands.

Comment: Could you rгn the `kubectl logs $podname`

Comment: Yes, I could run the following commands successfully.  

`kubectl describe pods <pod-name> --namespace <namespace-name>`

`kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <container-name> --namespace <namespace-name>`

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for this problem but not a good one.

I issued `--disable-filter` along with `kubectl proxy` command.  After that, I could execute `kubectl exec` commands successfully.

But when I use `--disable-filter`, it is prone to vulnerability. 
A message `Request filter disabled, your proxy is vulnerable to XSRF attacks, please be cautious` is displayed with `--disable-filter`.

so, I dont think that this is a good solution.

**Please let me know, if any one knows better solution for this problem.**

Answer (score 1):

By default, `kubectl proxy` rejects API commands matching `^/api/./pods/./exec`.

All you need to do in order to "bypass" this is start `kubectl proxy` with the appropriate flags:

`kubectl proxy --port 8080 --reject-paths "^/api/./pods/./attach"`

Of course, this comes with the security risk that anyone with access to your proxy can now exec into any of the pods on the cluster.

If you actually need to do this in a production environment, I highly recommend restricting what the proxy has access to using RBAC authorization - run the proxy as a Deployment with a ServiceAccount.

For more information, see:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#proxy
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/